# create route/view/controller dynamically by submitting form with slim PHP

Tags: php, routes, slim

What I can do :

Create a dashboard using eloquant with slim to be able to create for example a gallery with photos. The dashboard will contain all the created galleries, each gallery with a link to the gallery's page.

Problem :

I can't figure out how, with slim, I could add a button on the dashboard that will automatically upon submitting the button :

- Create a route :

`$app->get('/gallery1', 'GalleryController:gallery1')->setName('gallery1');`

- Create a view called gallery1.html.twig
- Update GalleryController.php to add a function to generate that view :

  `public function gallery1($request, $response)
      {
          return $this->container->view->render($response, 'gallery1.html.twig');
      }`

I thought about, rather than doing that, I could create a that creates a gallery/gallery1. Having gallery/ as the url containing all galleries and gallery1 as the one containing the gallery1 gallery. Even if, this won't solve the problem of generating views for each page :/ I can't seem to imagine how can I create this dynamically.

I'm new to Slim, sorry.

Comment: First you can create route pattern like '/{gallery}'. In GalleryController create method gallery which gets the route $args and creates new twig template, but it isn't the best solution.

Comment: This is is not how it's supposed to be done. Your solution for the first problem is correct, you need to have one route `/gallery` which accepts params (gallery number). But for the view...the whole point is to have one view fo all galleries, and pass different data to it. That is, to pass different images for example (for each gallery)